# 2014 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/2014-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until March 31st at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Ahh, the end is in sight.

Comment: Thanks! FYI: There's a bug on the election page [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/election) ... the link to meta is broken and missing the "stackexchange" part.

Comment: @C.Ross Not the "end" -- just the end of the beginning :)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The end of me being a mod here it is. :-)

Comment: @C.Ross Oh, I see. Well sir, thank you for your service!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 6):

If members of the community ask for changes to the allowed topics for the site; what should be the process for change be?  How would you decide to change the Money.SE help center based on the outcomes of meta.money discussions?

Answer (score 6):

How would you approach a new user to the site who has clearly asked an off-topic question or clearly used the answer as a discussion?  Assuming you will cast a close vote, how might you address the faux pas to the new user?

Answer (score 6):

How would you deal with a question that is clearly off-topic, but well liked by the community , i.e. it has a lot of upvotes and quality answers?

Note: Of course, I'm not talking about questions that are wildly off topic like "Who was a better captain, Kirk or Piccard?", but rather those that have some connection to money or finance, but aren't within the scope of what we have defined for the site.

**Example Scenario:**
**Question:** What caused the economic collapse of Japan in the 1990's?
45 upvotes, 3 downvotes

**Answers:**
Accepted/Top answer: 14 votes and is a very thorough treatment of the topic by someone who clearly has some economics background.

Comment: I'd shut down the wildly off topic question, but only after saying "Benjamin Sisko." We are at a loss at SE to handle Economics questions now that ESE has closed. The upvotes speak volumes.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer but who is the better sisco/cisco/sysco/sisqo?

Answer (score 5):

How will you contribute to a strong culture that welcomes new users and rewards good behavior from established users?

Answer (score 4):

How will you address the community if your feelings about the direction of the site are in conflict with the community's agreed upon direction as decided in meta.money?

Answer (score 3):

What role does community history have in guiding the future of the community?

Answer (score 2):

How will you react when a user lashes out at you, accusing you of being a {bully|idiot|a poor excuse for a human being} after you {close a question|delete an answer|delete a comment}?